# Encountered ValueError while assigning value to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm try to assign value to a dataframe. but I got

```
ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable
```

Here is my code:

```
env_5min.loc[index_last, ['price_action', 'pos_vwap', 'pos_ema9'] + PATTERN_RECOGNITION] \
            = movement_analysis(env_5min.iloc[-10:])
```

and I checked, the function returned a list with length 24 and the column length is also 24.

Here is the weird part, I changed the code with `for` loop:

```
analysis_list = movement_analysis(env_5min.iloc[-10:])
columns = ['price_action', 'pos_vwap', 'pos_ema9'] + PATTERN_RECOGNITION
for i in range(len(columns)):
    env_5min.loc[index_last, columns[i]] = analysis_list[i]
```

then it worked perfectly. Now the code is working alright, I'm just curious about the error and how to resolve it, and also wonder whether there is a more elegant way to assign value.